# Canot call methd 'getAt' of null, never ever calling getAt?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I get this error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getAt' of null sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.onItemTrigger sencha-touch-all.js:21
b.implement.callParent sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.onItemTrigger sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.doFire sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.fire sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.doDispatchEvent sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.dispatchEvent sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.doFireEvent sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.fireEvent sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.onItemTap sencha-touch-all.js:21
b.implement.callParent sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.onItemTap sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.doFire sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.fire sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.doDispatchEvent sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.dispatch sencha-touch-all.js:21
b.implement.callParent sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.dispatch sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.doPublish sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.publish sencha-touch-all.js:21
b.implement.callSuper sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.publish sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.onRecognized sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.fire sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.onTouchEnd sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.invokeRecognizers sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.onTouchEnd sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.onEvent sencha-touch-all.js:21
(anonymous function) sencha-touch-all.js:21
```

Funny is that none of my code is faulty there? Can someone help me or should i just live with it? What is crashing exactly, i can't figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error message - something wrong with the store. `getAt` is the method of the store class. Try to use not minified framework, this way your stack would make more sense and you will be able to see what exactly is going on.

Comment: I'm using architect which autogenerate... I dont know how to not minified :( And over that, there can't be problems with a store has all my stores are inlines (visual demo, not functional)

Comment: Can you post it as a fiddle?

Comment: I am facing same problem. I think this error occurs when we use hardcoded data in our store instead of pointing a model.